# Flow does keeps interpreting variables as Promises after async/await

Tags: async-await, es6-promise, flowtype

**Reproduction :**

```
// @flow
type A = { key: string, value: string};

const a:A = {
  key: 'a',
  value: 'a'
};

const foo = ():Promise<A> => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve(a);
        }, 1000);
    });
}

const bar = async ():A => {
    const res:A = ((await foo()):any);
    return res;
}

bar();
```

[Try it on flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagIKgLygDeoA1pqgFygDOyATgJYB2A5gDSgBuAhtAK6ZqdJmwC+AbkSIAxrGZ1QPSnkJFEoMhWoByHjvYbufQbv2JJ0uQuShIsWAVAAKAJSUACvVgBbRjUwAHhwAPgIw9QBIekxkfnpmUGZMeFAvX39MZ0h+ZhlkRnlnGJpYaC5MThiAK0x813VNTUiA5AAVRh9MWH5kbNz8wuY3Rqax6MxS8qyeVykxsbFOAEYABnW5o00xTbEreUUAIx56Jx4aVDyXd1UIxEjrRRKVJ2dnHngeRlt7WDd3HjMVCbZoxOIJUAlKR7RDHehuCRAA)

**Context :**

When calling a function called 'foo' returning a promise with await, the type of the variable is still Promise.

Flow correctly interprets the value if we just return the variable, but triggers an error if we type the return of the function called 'bar'.

```
19:         return res;
                   ^ Cannot return `res` because property `key` is missing in `Promise` [1] but exists in `A` [2].
References:
[LIB] static/v0.75.0/flowlib/core.js:583: declare class Promise<+R> {
                                                        ^ [1]
17:     const bar = async ():A => {
                             ^ [2]
```

**Solutions tried :**

- Forcing the type to 'A' of the variable calling await
- Casting with any then 'A' didn't seem to solve the error.

**Issues Related :**

https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5294

**Purpose of this question:**

I am mostly looking for a workaround

Comment: On stack overflow, code that is required to understand your question must be pasted directly into the question and formatted appropriately.  It is not permitted to have the only reference to the code be an external link.  This is because external links have a habit of changing or disappearing, thus rendering the question useless as a long term reference (which is one of stackoverflow's missions).

Comment: An `async` function ALWAYS returns a promise.  To get the value from that promise use `.then()` or `await`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to be a simple misunderstanding, but the error message from Flow isn't very useful.

You've declared `bar` as

```
const bar = async (): A => {
```

but async functions always return promises, so it should be

```
const bar = async (): Promise<A> => {
```

You can see it [here on flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagIKgLygDeoA1pqgFygDOyATgJYB2A5gDSgBuAhtAK6ZqdJmwC+AbkSIAxrGZ1QPSnkJFEoMhWoByHjvYbufQbv2JJ0uQuShIsWAVAAKAJSUACvVgBbRjUwAHhwAPgIw9QBIekxkfnpmUGZMeFAvX39MZ0h+ZhlkRnlnGJpYaC5MThiAK0x813VNTUiA5AAVRh9MWH5kbNz8wuY3Rqax6MxS8qyeVykxsbFOAEYABnW5o00xTbEreUUAIx56Jx4aVDyXdzTvPwDgsPwIxEjrRRLqVSV4HkZbeywNzzUATOIJUAlKR7RDHejAoA).

Comment: Indeed, I feel a bit dumb not finding this myself but this is the right answer